# What does this statement do "while(a[i]--!=0)"?

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, while-loop

Below is the code used for sorting numbers in non-decreasing order:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
# define size 1000001
static int a[size];
int main()
{
  int t, k, i;
  scanf("%d", &t);
  for(i = 0; i < t; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &k);
    a[k] += 1;
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 1000001; i++)
  {
    while(a[i]-- != 0)
      printf("%d\n", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

It would be really of great help if someone could explain the code to me. I have gone through the code and I have no idea as to how it can sort numbers. There is no swapping done at any place but still it works in c++ editor.

Comment: The first step to understanding it - indent it properly.

Comment: This looks like a simple [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) and it will overwrite innocent memory if you input a value greater than 1000000.

Comment: I would have simply written `while(a[i]--)` rather than `while(a[i]-- != 0)`. But I personally prefer `while(a[i]-- >= 0)`. Because, with `while(a[i]-- != 0)` I have run into infinite loop issues when the input values have negative integers.

Comment: I find that if you don't understand the program, a debugger will shed some light. Of course you need to understand the language. The point is here that first the comparison is done, then a decrement of the value because it is postfix decrement. The fact that it is an array element just makes it look more complicated than that.

Answer (score 2):

This program doesn't sort numbers in a mathematical sense, but that isn't important since it gives you the illusion of doing it.

The program asks for `t`, which would be better named `numberOfValues`... the number of values you will input.

The array `a[size]` can be thought of as `size` buckets of values. In your program, these `buckets` are simply counters. Each bucket has a number, 0 through size. When value `5` is input, bucket `a[5]` has its count increased. This continues until all buckets are set.

The program then works through the buckets. Most of your buckets will be empty, but when a bucket is non-zero (`while a[i] != 0` -- ignore the missing `--` for now), the bucket needs to be "emptied" while at the same time, its contents need to be accounted for. The bucket `a[i]` holds the count of `i` elements, so the loop prints that a value of `i` is next in the sort, while also decrementing the count (`a[i]--`). This continues until the bucket is empty (`== 0`) and the program moves to the next bucket.

Eventually all of your buckets have been emptied and the sort is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Decrements variable `a[i]` until it's 0 while printing it out every time

Answer (score 0):

There is no swapping because is not needed: numbers are not stored as usual, it uses a huge array to mark which number has been entered:

If you add the number 200, it stores array[200]=1. If you add again 200, then array[200]=2.

Then, it prints the array in the following way: imagine you have [0,1,2,1,0,0...], so there is one 1, two 2, one 3...
So it just shows 1,2,2,3

Answer (score 0):

The code iterates for each value in the array `a`. Each value `a[i]` in the array is iterated in the while loop. `while(a[i]--!=0)` checks if the value of a[i] is zero. If not, the loop body is executed. When the control enters the loop body, decrementing the a[i] value. Eg) If a[i]=6, the output will be:

```
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider for i=0;
Then `a[i]--!=0` will get executed till value at `a[i]` does not become `zero`.When value at `a[i]` becomes `zero` while loop will get terminated and next iteration of `for` loop will start.

Answer (score 0):

its a nice code but its space complexity is high.

This part of the code

```
for(i = 0; i < t; i++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &k);
    a[k] += 1;
  }
```

stores frequency of number entered (its somewhat like hashing)

say if I entered  `5  4  2  4  2`

then

```
a[5] =1 
a[4] =2
a[2] =2
```

all others will be zero

so if you want to say find frequency of "n" in the array then just print `a[n]`

---

lets come to your questions now

*how this code sorts the number ?*

*what's use of `while(a[i]--!=0)`?*

**Answer to first question :**

we go from 0 to 1000001 in oder so if 4 2 5 6 is entered

As the loop goes from 0 to 100001 first it checks a[2] !=0 then a[4] later a[5] then a[6]  all non zero frequency terms are printed .

so as per checking oder first 2 4 5 6 is printed

**Answer to the second question :**

why isn't is `while(a[i]!=0)` because iam checking only if its non zero if its non zero lets print the number

but say i entered 4 3 2 4 2

then the output should print 2 2 3 4 4

so `while(a[i] --!=0)` is used it prints the number a[i] times say if

a[4]=2 which means 4 is present 2 times hence its should print 4 4 so while loop runs twice as a[4] =2